# Strip span from h1 in Python (Beautiful soup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm unable to delete the span from the H1 - I need just the H1 text without the text within the span:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/524901")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
weather_desc_today = soup.find(class_="wr-day__weather-type-description").get_text()
weather_location = soup.find('h1').text
print (weather_location)
```

Outputs:

```
Moscow - Weather warnings issued
```

When I need just 'Moscow'

Here's the HTML:

```
<h1 id="wr-location-name-id" tabindex="-1" class="wr-c-location__name gel-paragon">Moscow<span class="gs-u-vh wr-c-warnings-issued"> - <!-- -->Weather warnings issued</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find`.

```
weather_location = soup.find('h1').find(text=True)

OUT: Moscow
```